# requesting date from a multi-dimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$tmb = Array(
             [xThis] => 12400
             [fThat] => 7
             [cMore] => Array(
                    [236] => Array(
                        [acting_person] => "Test info"
                        [tThings] => "history"
                        )
                    )
               )
          )
```

I know how to call xThis(like $tmb['xThis']
but how do I call [acting_person] in a statement like this?

```
$new = $tmb['xThis'] . $tmb['fThat'] . ??????????????????
```

Sorry If this is elementary I am really new to PHP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *access* (not "call") a subarray like this:

```
$tmb['cMore'][236]['acting_person']
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the acting_person item, you'd need to specify all of acting_person's parent keys. (You could theoretically have multiple acting_person keys in a multi-dimensional array, of course.)

```
$new = $tmb['xThis'] . $tmb['fThat'] . $tmb['cMore'][236]['acting_person'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to access the value of any dimension of array

```
   $tmb['1st dimension'][2nd dimensin]['3rd dimension'][..][...][..]
```

even more just provide the key  [key]